# Сериализация пустого ArrayList в json в виде []

Tags: java, json, jackson

Использую com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype

При сериализации коллекции с одним объектом получаю

```
return Collections.singletonList(new Offer());

"offers": [
        {}
    ]
```

мне нужно чтобы вернулось

```
"offers": []
```

не получается добиться такого вывода. Если просто пустой список вернуть, то запись пропадает.

Comment: `return new ArrayList<Offer>();` не поможет?

Comment: Вы очень странного хотите. Не стоит в этом случае удивляться, что "стандарт" так не работает. Но jackson имеет кое-какие опции по кастомизации сериализации/десериализации. Курите манул в этом направлении.

Comment: return new ArrayList<Offer>(); - пустой json

Comment: @Sergey возможно, стандарная отработка этот кейс не покрывает. может другая либа справиться?

Comment: jackson имеет кое-какие опции по кастомизации сериализации/десериализации. Курите манул в этом направлении. https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Comment: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-include-non-empty.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решение юзать JsonSerializer

```java
public class CustomMyObjectSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyObject> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(MyObjectvalue, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeArrayFieldStart("offers");
        if (!value.getOffers().isEmpty()) {
            for (SpecialsOfferDetailsResponse r : value.getOffers())
                jgen.writeObject(r);
        }
        jgen.writeEndArray();
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<SpecialsResponse> handledType() {
        return SpecialsResponse.class;
    }
}
```

потом добавить бин

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public SimpleModule getMod() {
        SimpleModule mod = new SimpleModule("MyModule");
        mod.addSerializer(new CustomSpecialsResponseSerializer());
        return mod;
    }
}
```

и над контроллером

```java
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomMyObjectSerializer .class)
```